# How to convert a uint16 to a 2 byte string in Go?

Tags: string, go, int, type-conversion

I am dealing with some legacy data where I routinely need to convert a uint16 to a 2 byte string.

Here is what I am using (where i is a uint16):

```
string([]byte {byte(i >> 8), byte(i & 0xFF)})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/423CAL-SJv

This seems rather clunky. Is there an existing library function to do this? I have looked at both the strings and binary packages, but nothing seemed immediately obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While that is perfectly fine for what you're trying to do, the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package has much more functionality for reading and writing binary values.

You can use

```
i := uint16(0x474F)

b := make([]byte, 2)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(b, i)
fmt.Println(string(b))
// GO
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IdDnnOtS2V

Comment: Thank you for that. I had read over the encoding/binary page but was thrown off by varint in the names.

Answer (score -4):

Try the following

```
t := strconv.Itoa(123)
```

Comment: @Xevious, Sorry for my quick response, I understood the question wrong. Apologies.