# Convert *uint16 to string in Golang

Tags: c, go, pointers

In golang, `syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr` to convert a `string` to `*uint16`.

how to convert `*uint16` back to `string`?

Situation is a `*uint16` is returned by a `C` function, I want to convert
it to `string`, any idea to do it?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using the `syscall` package and not, say, `strconv`?

Comment: Yes, I use `syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr` to convert `string` to `*uint16` . 
 Because some C function export in go require `*uint16`

Comment: Use the inverse function from the same package, [`syscall.UTF16ToString`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall?GOOS=windows#UTF16ToString)

Comment: `syscall.UTF16ToString param` receive `[]uint16` not *uint16

Comment: May be duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876914/how-to-convert-a-uint16-to-a-2-byte-string-in-go

Comment: Simply call `syscall.UTF16ToString([]uint16{*ptr})`, where ptr is of type *uint16 (or `unicode/utf16.Decode([]uint16{*ptr})` directly).